# How should a prepared selection in PHP be?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to secure my database from SQL-injections and I can't seem to make this statement to work. I've done this a few times already and those attempts work but not this one.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT name, pass, email FROM users WHERE salt=?");

$stmt->bind_param("s", $salt); 
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->bind_result($stuff1,$stuff2,$stuff3);
$stmt->store_result();
while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
  var_dump($stuff1." - ".$stuff2." - ".$stuff3."<br />");
  }
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();
```

I've managed to get that it works all the way to execute by placing var_dumps but I don't get why the results/fetch don't work. Is there a simple explanation to what I've missed?

EDIT: What I'm expecting is to retrieve name, pass and email from my table but instead I just get NULL.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: error reporting and `mysqli_error($db)` are a good start.

Comment: your methods are out of order.

Comment: @IncredibleHat it's valid, just not in the right spot, as is some of their other methods.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords with a weak, high-speed hash like SHA1 or MD5**.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if($stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT name, pass, email FROM users WHERE salt=?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $salt); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt->bind_result($name, $pass, $email);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo "{$name} - {$pass} - {$email}<br>";
    }
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    print_r($db->errorInfo()); 
}
```

Key changes are checking if `$stmt` is set before any parameters do anything. You also don't need `store_result()` or `free_result()`. Also, I added an `else` statement that should display an error if `$stmt` was not able to be set.

Note: You should use **PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)** (`password_hash()` and `password_verify()`) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). **It is not necessary** to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Selecting by salt is an extremely concerning thing to be doing in the first place.

Comment: @tadman Yes it is. I've put a notice to not store plain text passwords, I assume if the OP fixed that it would fix searching by salt by proxy.

Comment: A salt is necessary, but saving it in a separate column is a technique that faded out in the 1990s. The Bcrypt format embeds the salt in the final hash. I don't think these passwords are plain-text, but they seem to be badly implemented.

Comment: @tadman Right, so storing the passwords using `password_hash()` as I mentioned in my answer would inevitably force OP to stop searching by salt because it would no longer be being used.

Comment: I think that's a good idea to use `password_hash`, absolutely, but I don't think they're plain-text, that's all.

Comment: @tadman I removed that part from my answer :)